# How can I Simultaneous login to all the Virtual Terminals?

Tags: auto-login, virtual-terminal

This is a Ubuntu 12.04 Minimal Install.

When I scroll across these 6 terminals using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> through
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> , 
I have to independently login each of them; one-by-one.

Is their any way out that I may login to all of these 6 terminals in one go??

Comment: The answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9266401/login-to-multiple-ttys-from-one-tty looks similar to what you're after, in general, you would use [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) or [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) (both available in the Ubuntu repositories) for enabling and managing multiple terminals though.

Comment: unfortunately this method uses SSH keys, which I don't want to. could there be something like federal login for all the terminals?

Comment: Just curious, Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @Mitch, since I am logged into one terminal, that means I am authenticated user. now i want to do this for example the tty1 gets occupied if i run startx. now to do apt-get i need tty2 and to simultaneously edit some file by vim i will surly require tty3. now   it would be a great convenience if i log into tty1 and it comes along all the tty's.. :-)

Comment: Have a look at this http://linuxgazette.net/issue69/henderson.html

Comment: I don't know how to do that, but you can use something like `byobu` to achieve the "same" effect. It's really handy when working in console mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit as super user the files named `/etc/init/ttyx.conf` (where x can be 1 to 6) as follows:

```
sudo gedit /etc/init/tty1.conf
```

find

```
exec /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1
```

and comment it:

```
#exec /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1
```

Write below:

```
exec /bin/login -f USERNAME < /dev/tty1 > /dev/tty1 2>&1
```

where USERNAME is yours.

If you still want to start GUI, add startx to your bash profile:

```
sudo -s
echo "startx" >> $HOME/.bash_profile
```

or, if this won't work, open your user’s .bashrc file:

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

Add the following to the end of the file:

```
if [ $(tty) == "/dev/tty1" ]; then
startx
fi
```

Comment: Plz if any one Verify & Check .....So i can award the bounty ..

Comment: So fat i've been searching for a solutions, but everything is in vain..  hope to find some intelligent idea this time.. may i bump this question !